How to make the quicksort algorithm stable?
I implemented the quicksort Algorithm in java but am struggling to make it stable. (the order of equal elements has to stay the same)
I would really appreciate any further help.
this is my current code:
@Override
    public void quickSortStable(Integer[] data) {


        quickSort(data, 0, data.length - 1);

    }

    private static void quickSort(Integer[] data, int start, int end) {

        if (start>= end) return; 

        int pivot = partition(data, start, end);

        quickSort(data, start, pivot -1); 
        quickSort(data, pivot +1, end); 

    }

    private static int partition(Integer[] data, int start, int end){

        int pivot= data[end]; 
        int i = start -1;

        for (int j = start; j<= end; j++){
            if(data[j]< pivot){
                i++;
                //variable swap i and j
                int temp = data[i];
                data[i]=data[j];
                data[j]= temp;

            }
        }
        
        i++;
        int temp = data[i];
        data[i]=data[end];
        data[end]= temp;

        return i; 

    }


How can you tell that it is not stable (=not preserving the original order of equal elements) on integers? Or do you mean some different kind of stable? Please provide a [mre] ideally with hardcoded example data that demonstrates your problem.

change:s use int or Integer, but not both - since temp is a primitive, the original instances are eventually changed by cached instances. If using int, the sorting can only be stable. If using Integer (or other non-primitive): change the condition to if (data[j] <= pivot) (so that every same value that was before the pivot is still moved before it)

@user85421 - At the end of partition, assume that i indexes the first element > pivot and equal to the next element. When the pivot is swapped into place, that first element > pivot is swapped to end, putting it after what was the next element it was equal to, resulting in an unstable sort.

@rcgldr correct, that would be the next correction, not to hard to do

@teapot418 - split the integers into two parts, the upper part is has the value to be sorted, the lower part has the index. Change the compare to only compare the upper part. Once sorted, check for out of order equal values+indexes (can just compare entire integer to do this).

@user85421 - The element to be swapped could be equal to any of the values to the right of the element, so a scan, and rotate if needed would be done, not difficult, but slower.

As the Wikipedia article on Quicksort states:

Most implementations of quicksort are not stable

...and:

In-place partitioning is used. This unstable partition requires O(1) space.

...but:

Another, less common, not-in-place, version of quicksort uses O(n) space for working storage and can implement a stable sort. The working storage allows the input array to be easily partitioned in a stable manner and then copied back to the input array for successive recursive calls.

So, if it is OK to use space for working storage, you could temporarily collect the values that are greater than the pivot in a separate array. Once all the other values have been moved to the left side of the partition, including the pivot, you can then flush the values from that separate array back to the original array, guaranteeing their order in case of equal keys.
Here is how your partition function could look to implement that:
    private static int partition(Integer[] data, int start, int end) {
        // Reserve memory for collecting values greater than the pivot
        Integer[] greater = new Integer[end - start + 1];
        int numGreater = 0; // number of values greater than pivot
        int pivot = data[end];
        int i = start - 1;
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
            if (data[j] <= pivot) { // Include pivot value
                i++;
                data[i] = data[j];
            } else {
                greater[numGreater] = data[j]; // Set this value aside
                numGreater++;
            }
            
        }
        // Flush the values that were put aside
        for (int j = 0; j < numGreater; j++) {
            data[i + 1 + j] = greater[j];
        }
        return i;
    }



I implemented the quicksort Algorithm in java but am struggling to make it stable. (the order of equal elements has to stay the same) I'm not allowed to use the java libraries. (in particular the java.util package).

if you want to make sure that your quicksort algorithm be stable, you should keep the order of equal elements remains unchanged after sorting.
First thing I recommend you to use an Integer class as object wrapper instead of a int as primitive type for your array elements. It is important because with primitive types, the original instances are eventually changed by cached instances, making it impossible to maintain stability.
Secondly, modify the partitioning logic to include elements less than or equal to the pivot in the left partition. This way you ensure that elements with the same value as the pivot remain in their original relative order.

At the end of partition, assume that i indexes the first element > pivot and equal to the next element. When the pivot is swapped into place, that first element > pivot is swapped to end, putting it after what was the next element it was equal to, resulting in an unstable sort.
